# PHP last month in other language

Tags: php, datetime

in PHP, I want to display the last month in my language (German). 
I found a working snippet for the translation:

```
<?php $monate = array(1=>"Januar",
            2=>"Februar",
            3=>"M&auml;rz",
            4=>"April",
            5=>"Mai",
            6=>"Juni",
            7=>"Juli",
            8=>"August",
            9=>"September",
            10=>"Oktober",
            11=>"November",
            12=>"Dezember");
$monat = date("n");
echo $monate[$monat]; ?>
```

And also a good one for the last month:

```
<?php $date=date_create("2013-05-01");
date_modify($date,"first day of last month");
echo date_format($date,"M"); ?>
```

But equal what I try I don't manage to combine those two. 
E.g.:

```
<?php $monate = array(1=>"Januar",
2=>"Februar",
3=>"M&auml;rz",
4=>"April",
5=>"Mai",
6=>"Juni",
7=>"Juli",
8=>"August",
9=>"September",
10=>"Oktober",
11=>"November",
12=>"Dezember");
$monat = date("n");
monat_modify($date,"last month");
echo $monate[$monat]; ?>
```

No way ... :-) Any hint how to get those two combined?

Comment: You used monat_modify instead of date_modify :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $monate = 
       array(
            1=>"Januar",
            2=>"Februar",
            3=>"M&auml;rz",
            4=>"April",
            5=>"Mai",
            6=>"Juni",
            7=>"Juli",
            8=>"August",
            9=>"September",
            10=>"Oktober",
            11=>"November",
            12=>"Dezember"
            );


$data_time = new DateTime();

//date_modify($data_time,"last month"); //date_modify modifies the timestamp. ex: last month, + 15 days etc..

$data_time->modify("last month"); // you can also use modify funtion for timestamp.  ex: last month, + 15 days etc..

$last_month = $data_time->format("n"); // return last month in number ex: 4

echo $monate[$last_month]; // prints the last months value from array

?>
```

Comment: Works! And this is even more elegant, since it is absolutely ease to choose not only next or previous months, but -3 or +8 months etc. too. Thanks! .-)

Comment: your welcome !! bro :)  check mark  if its work for you !!

Comment: Won't this fail if the current month is January?

Comment: hmm you are right @SteveLovell  , so i modify my ans you can check it !! :) thnx

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$monat = date("n");
monat_modify($date,"last month");
echo $monate[$monat];
```

with

```
$monat = date_create();
date_modify($monat,"last month");
$monat = date_format($monat,"n");
echo $monate[$monat];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work either. 
** Warning: date_modify() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in /www/htdocs/.../header-footer/plugin.php(488) : eval()‚d code on line 14

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in /www/htdocs/...header-footer/plugin.php(488) : eval()‚d code on line 15 **

Comment: err forgot the translation... my brain's a bit slow today!

Comment: still faster than mine :-) but also the new code doesn't work. no output at all now ...

Comment: That's it! Thank you :-) As I'm a newbie my upvote isn't counted yet. Of course I gave you every up I could. Thanks again!